# bootstrapvalidator not working on jquery post append form

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I call a form through jquery post (using navbar menu) the form appends correctly but when try to run the validations they're not working.
If I use the form embedded instead of calling it, all the validations work fine. What am I missing?

```
 $.post('php/getform.php', null, function(dat) {
             $('#formval').append(dat);
             $("#formval").bootstrapValidator();
             });
         });
        $("#formval").bootstrapValidator({
               framework: 'bootstrap',
        fields: {
                   email:{
                        message: "Email vacio!",
                        validators: {
           ...........
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I missed passing variable to  $("#formval").bootstrapValidator().
To do this I created a variable in json form containing the validation structure:

```
var option={ framework: 'bootstrap',
    fields: {
               email:{
                    message: "Email vacio!",
                    validators: {
              .....
             }
```

And then I passed it to the validation instance:

```
$("#forma").bootstrapValidator(option);
```

This post helped me a lot:
[Bootstrap validation on dynamically adding multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556313/bootstrap-validation-on-dynamically-adding-multiple-fields)